# Editorial Board Members and EBM Agreement

Tags: publishers, journal-workflow

I have to know about recruiting editorial board members (EBMs). How to find EBM agreement (for free-charge members)?

Comment: Just ask. They can say no if they wish.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.  Are you asking about recruiting members?  Are you asking about rules for members?  Are you asking for legal advice?

Answer (score 1):

This seems too much a one-person operation. People will agree with your decisions or not, but it is less likely if they have had no input into the structure of your operation.

Rather than invite people *late* to the board, it would be better if you invite a few people to assist you in setting policies and such and then, after a joint effort, form a board.

People are busy. But the way you state the question it seems like there will be little benefit for anyone to participate. And, if you make a broad call, you will, perhaps, get volunteers for the wrong reasons.

But if you don't have people in your circle who could help you, and who have the appropriate skills and standing, then, depending on the field, people who regularly volunteer for things like conference committee membership may have the right mind-set to assist.